# android app with google-play-services_lib display a marker but not the the map

Tags: android

I need to display a map with a marker in my app. The marker is diplayed but the map is not displayed.

```
    gps = new GPSTracker(this);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        final LatLng STANDORT = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(STANDORT)
                .title(getString(R.string.standort)));
    }
        .
        .
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(STANDORT, 12));
```

Comment: Try moving your app/libs to /system/ and see if this fixes it. I have seen such behaviour for example with locations in G+ when I tried to make it non-system app. I think it's a bug with play services

Comment: This looks like a problem with your API key. Did you follow all steps to generate and add your API key? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start